# How do I convert string of unicode code to plain text in Python 3.?

Tags: python, unicode

There's a whole bunch of answers to the similar questions here on Stack and in Google, but all of those seems irrelevant. I'm afraid that problem is in the question but still do need a solution nonetheless.

The code:

```
print(type(comment))
print(comment)
```

Results in:

```
<class 'str'>
\u041d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043e
```

How do I convert this to plain text?

upd.

```
print(comment[0])
```

Returns

```
\
```

Comment: Just to make sure what does your string actually contain, could you tell us whether `comment[0]` is `"\"`, or `"\u41d"`?

Comment: It's '\'. Will add it to the topic.

Comment: Are you trying to pritn `Не указано`?

Comment: Yes, I assume it's some text in Russian.

Comment: @KatShot I posted the answer. Take a look, is that what you wanted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you started with a `str` in Python 3, you need to encode to bytes then decode using the `unicode-escape` codec to translate those literal escape codes to Unicode:

```
comment = r'\u041d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043e'
print(type(comment))
print(comment)
print(comment.encode('ascii').decode('unicode-escape'))
```

Output:

```
<class 'str'>
\u041d\u0435 \u0443\u043a\u0430\u0437\u0430\u043d\u043e
Не указано
```

Comment: Thank you, a straightforward solution!

Answer (score 1):

Two answers in one:

If you really want to get it parsed quickly, you can do something like this:

```
import ast
s = ast.literal_eval('"' + comment.replace('"', '\\"') + '"')
```

`s` will contain what you want - it will process the string, as if you wrote it in your code this way.

(this is safer than actual eval, because it will not allow comment to execute any functions - but you can still break it by including a `\"` in the comment)

To process it correctly though, you'd have to write a proper lexer/parser to analyse it character by character.

But really, if you ended up with that string, something is wrong somewhere before. You ended up with a string with escaped unicode instead of actual contents. If it comes from somewhere in your application, the best way would be to trace back to where it originates and ensure you don't end up in this situation in the first place.

Comment: The string comes directly from Russian website code - I honestly have no idea how they come up with this encoding, since there's a pure Russian language in one part of the page, and then there's this Unicode mess in another part (of that same page).

Comment: @Pradam For python2 you need to use `ast.literal_eval('u"' + ....`. The original question is about python3

Comment: @KatShot I understand it's coming from the outside source - what i meant is how it gets in your code from the place where it's read from the website to the place where you use it and see the current value. I suspect it's not broken like that from the beginning. (not seeing the code, I may be wrong of course)

Comment: @viraptor Firstly, I navigate page via in-browser "developers tools" and "inspect page code". And then I use requests to get .text or .content of the page - comment variable is just a result of several .split functions applied to the r.text, no logic or encoding applied.